# Google Sheets: Create a button that will send attendance data to another spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

First, let me provide some context. I work with a program that provides tutoring for students. We use the Google Suite. Currently, we have a "Dashboard" spreadsheet with our students and volunteers listed on it. Beside each name is a spot to mark their attendance for the night (this makes it quick to visualize each night, so we can make calls if necessary). Then, a staff member will copy/paste the attendance data for the night into our "Attendance" spreadsheet.

Helpful sheet examples: let's say on the "Dashboard" that Student names go from B2:B6 and their attendance markers are A2:A6, and that Volunteer names go from C2:C6 and their attendance markers are D2:D6. On the "Attendance," let's say that student & volunteer names go A2:A13, and the program night dates go from B1:F1

The goal is a button on the "Dashboard" that anyone can click, which will send over the attendance data to the "Attendance" spreadsheet by matching the names and putting it under the right date.

Let me know if this is possible -- my knowledge of script limitations is very limited! Thank you!

Comment: Please share an example of your work.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't too sure of what you wanted exactly, so I've come up with the following.

## Dashboard

I've made a dashboard based on your description which ended up looking like this.

[image: Dashboard]

Here you can enter the names of the student and the volunteer from A2 and B2 downwards respectivly. In C1 you can see the current date, which is just the `=TODAY()` formula (which I wrote down in D1 just for reference).

Then you can use the rest of the C column to note the attendance.

After you've filled out the attendence you can click a button (in this case I just made one) that's linked to the script like in the picture.

## Script

As for the script, I made this little thing:

```js
function studentStuff() {
  // getting all data from dashboard
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const date = ss.getRange('C1').getValue();
  const data = ss.getRange('A2:C').getValues();

  // get the sheet to work in where to "save" the attendance
  const spreadSheetID = 'PUT SHEET ID HERE';
  const attendanceSheetName = 'PUT SHEET NAME HERE';
  const attendanceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadSheetID).getSheetByName(attendanceSheetName);

  // insert the data
  attendanceSheet.insertColumns(1,3);
  attendanceSheet.getRange('A1').setValue(date);
  attendanceSheet.getRange('A2:C').setValues(data);
  
  // Cleaning attendance
  ss.getRange('C2:C6').setValue('FALSE');
}
```

## Result

Now here's a little demo of what it does.
[image]